# How prove $f(a_{i})=0$ if $\int_{0}^{1}x^kf(x)dx=0,k=1,2,3,\cdots,n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

> let $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$,and such 
>   $$\int_{0}^{1}x^kf(x)dx=0,k=0,1,2,3,\cdots,n$$

show that: there exsit $n+1$ different $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n},a_{n+1}(a_{i}\neq a_{j},\forall i,j\in[1,n+1])\in [a,b]$,

such that
$$f(a_{1})=f(a_{2})=\cdots =f(a_{n})=f(a_{n+1})=0$$

It is easy to prove $n=1$,
Let $$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt,F(0)=F(1)=0$$
and
$$\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}xdF(x)=xF(x)|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}F(x)dx=0$$
so
$$\int_{0}^{1}F(x)dx=0$$
so there exsit  $\xi\in(0,1)$ such $F(\xi)=0$
so
$$F(0)=F(1)=F(\xi)=0$$
so $$F'(\eta_{1})=F'(\eta_{2})=0$$
so
$$f(\eta_{1})=f(\eta_{2})=0,\eta_{1}\neq\eta_{2}$$
so it prove by done,But for general,I can't

because I can't comment, Paramanand Singh,Hello,I read your solution, and you $d=e$ is possible,so I think your methods have some problem

Comment: You should continue the proof and note the pattern. Prove that integral of $xF(x)$ is also zero.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/443266/72031

Comment: There is a very simple argument here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443266/prove-the-exsistence-of-3-zero-points-of-a-function/446004#446004